# JQuery version compatible with JQuery UI and JQuery tablesorter

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery tablesorter plug-in and JQuery dialog plug-in in my program and JQuery tablesorter plug-in is working properly but the JQuery dialog plug-in is not working properly.

I have got to know that the problem is with the JQuery version.So I want to know which JQuery version is compatible with  JQuery UI 1.10.4 and JQuery tablesorter 2.0.1 ?

Comment: Rather then asking compatibility questions between jQuery UI and jQuery, You should share which versions are you using and with actual errors. It would be difficult for Stack overflow people to help you without such details.

Comment: I am jquery ui 1.10.4 and jquery tablesorter 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

As noted on the [jQuery UI Intro page](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/#step-3-choose-a-version-of-jquery-ui):

> Step 3: Choose a Version of jQuery UI
>
> The last step in the Download Builder is to select a version number.
>   This is a very important step because jQuery UI versions are designed
>   to work with specific versions of jQuery. The current versions are:
>
> ```
> jQuery UI 1.10.2 – Requires jQuery 1.6 or later.
> jQuery UI 1.9.2 – Requires jQuery 1.6 or later.
> ```

From personal experience with using UI 1.10.2 & Tablesorter 2.14.5 (as well as at least half a dozen earlier 2,x versions) I can say that Jquery 1.10.2 works fine and any 1.6X+ **should** work fine.

Comment: In my code I am using jquery ui 1.10.4 with jquery tablesorter 2.0.1 and tablesorter is working fine but the dialog plug-in is not working properly.

Comment: what errors are you getting? you can check the firebug in Firefox or developer console in crome.

Comment: @user3378361 and what dialog plug in isn't working/how isn't it working/as Santosh Joshi said what errors?

Comment: There are no errors but the dialog box is not showing up,only the lines written under it are displayed but nothing happens on clicking OK or Cancel button.Thats my problem.

Comment: @user3378361 then include your code so that we can actually review your code to find the problem rather than making at best informed guesses.